# Find the elements that have order $4$.

Tags: group-theory

$G=\Bigg\{
\begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a}       & \overline{b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\text{with $\overline{a}$ in $\mathbb{F}_5^*$ and $\overline{b}$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$} \Bigg\}$

$G$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$, the matrix group of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices with coefficients modulo $5$. Find a formula for $\begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a}       & \overline{b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix}^4$ and determine which elements of $G$ have order $4$.

---

So my first question is if matrix multiplication is done the 'normal' way like we're used to with matrices that have coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. The modulo thing threw me off, but I just assumed that multiplication should be carried out normally with $\overline{x}\cdot \overline{y}$ equaling $\overline{xy}$.

I calculated the following:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a}       & \overline{b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix}^4 = \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a}       & \overline{b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix}^2 \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a}       & \overline{b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a^2}       & \overline{(a+1)b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a^2}       & \overline{(a+1)b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{a^4}       & \overline{(a^3+a^2+a+1)b}  \\
    \overline{0}       & \overline{1} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

For an element to be of order $4$ it needs to equal the identity element when we rise it to the fourth power. That means that $\overline{a^4}$ has to equal $\overline{1}$, thus $\overline{a}=\overline{1}$. From this it follows that $\overline{4b}=\overline{0}$ and that can only be the case when $\overline{b}=\overline{0}$.

So the only element that can possibly be of order is the identity element itself, but the identity element has order $1$ and not order $4$, so there is no such element. However I'm pretty sure that's not correct. I'm messing up somewhere but I don't know where.

Comment: Note: Since $\mathbb F_5^*$ is a group with four elements, every element raised to the fourth power equals 1.

Answer (score 1):

Note $a^4 = 1 $ in $\mathbb{F_5}^\star$

${(a^3+a^2+a+1)\cdot b}$ has to be 0 mod 5. So try different values for a and b. eg if $a = 1 $ then $(1^3+1^2+1+1) \cdot b = 4 \cdot b $ which gives us $b=0$

For $a=2$ we have $15 \cdot b $ mod 5 which is true for all $b \in \mathbb{F}_5$

For $a=3$ we have $40 \cdot b $ mod 5 which is true for all $b \in \mathbb{F}_5$

For $a=4$ we have $85 \cdot b $ mod 5 which is true for all $b \in \mathbb{F}_5$

Comment: Thanks! It's all clear now. Last question, the way we multiply matrices doesn't change because we're working in $\mathbb{F}_5^{(*)}$, does it?

Comment: Another way to see that $(a^3+a^2+a+1)=0$ is to realize that multiplying by $a$ just permutes the elements of the sum, ie. $a\cdot(a^3+a^2+a+1)=(1+a^3+a^2+a)$.  If $ac=c$, then $(1-a)c=0$, and since $(1-a)\neq 0$, we get $c=0$.

Comment: @Olly and yes, matrix multiplication is defined the same for any field, or any ring in fact.